# How do I convert this line to haml?

Tags: haml

How can I convert the following line to haml:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= asset_path "favicon.ico" %>" />`

I tried using the following but it throws an error in rails:

`%link{href: asset_path "favicon.ico", rel: "shortcut icon"}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `asset_path(...)` not `asset_path ...`:

```
%link{href: asset_path("favicon.ico"), rel: "shortcut icon"}/
```

The issue is with the Ruby this compiles to. Your HAML is producing something like this pseudo code:

```
tag("link", href: asset_path "favicon.ico", rel: "shortcut icon")
```

This is syntactically ambiguous; Ruby can't know which of the following you intended:

```
tag(href: asset_path("favicon.ico"), rel: "...")
tag(href: asset_path("favicon.ico", rel: "..."))
```

So Ruby chooses to raise a syntax error in this case, forcing you to write unambiguous code.

Comment: Why does that need brackets while this doesn't?... `= javascript_include_tag "wise/application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true`